# why cant i target a element inside td or tr tags without a table tag in html?

Tags: html, css

```css
td span{color:red}
```

```html
<td>
   <span>hi</span>
</td>
```

I'm unable to target the `span` tag by mentioning `td` in CSS. Why it's happening? I can target the span tag by using `span {color:red}` or wrap the content inside a table with tr tag, but not by the above code

Comment: can you post your whole <table> tag?

Comment: Is your `<td>` properly nested within a `<table>` element? Have you used dev tools to “inspect element”?

Comment: there is no table tag. When I was answering some StackOverflow questions I came across this issue where I wasn't able to target anything with td as a selector. So I checked why was it happening there were no answers so I posted that as a question

Comment: Well, a `<td>` element is invalid unless it’s wrapped within a `<tr>` element, and that must be wrapped appropriately within a `<table>`. If you inspect the element I imagine that the browser will have tried to rescue your html markup to create something that’s valid.

Comment: ohkk so If i mention td without tr or table tag and tr without a table tag it is a invalid syntax but browser will try to make it a valid HTML by ignoring those tags. Is my understanding correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TD` can be inside `TABLE` only.  Than it'll work.

```css
td span {color: red;}
```

```html
<td><span>This one is outside TABLE, isn't red</span></td>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>red</span>
</table>
```

Comment: I know TD inside TABLE will work but I was wondering why without Table it's not working. that's why I raised this question. Anyway, I got the answer to the why part in the comments. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @kishoreRajendran: because it's invalid HTML and `TD` is ignored (see the generated DOM, it's `<html><head></head><body><span>hi</span></body></html>`). There is no `td` in DOM, so your CSS can't target anything.

Comment: just now noticed it thank you for clarifying :) @parvel

Answer (score 0):

td is only inside the table:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <h1>The span element</h1>

    <p>My mother has <span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">blue</span> eyes and my father has <span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">dark green</span> eyes.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eh... Any relation to question?